# ant design react flexbox not using full width

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I'm using antd forms in react, but my input is not using full width

[image: ant-design forms]

```
    <div className='loginForm'>
      <Form
        className='form'
        name="basic"
        labelCol={{
          span: 8,
        }}
        wrapperCol={{
          span: 16,
        }}
        style={{
          maxWidth: 600,
        }}
        initialValues={{
          remember: true,
        }}
        onFinish={onFinish}
        onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
        autoComplete="off">

        <Form.Item
          name="email"
          rules={[
            {
              required: true,
              message: 'Please input your email!',
            },
          ]}
        >
          <Input placeholder='Email' />
        </Form.Item>

        <Form.Item
          name="password"
          rules={[
            {
              required: true,
              message: 'Please input your password!',
            },
          ]}
        >
          <Input.Password placeholder='Password' />
        </Form.Item>
 </div>
```

Why does it not extend to the full width?

I know this is probably really simple but i can't work it out, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Remember to [show the relevant code in your post](/help/how-to-ask), too.

Comment: Your `Form.Item` elements don't have a style attribute, so they're just using default sizing?

Comment: `Form.Item` was given width of 100vh (percentage dont work), still it doesn't work

Comment: You need to change wrapperCol span to 24. 24 is maximum span you can specify. For responsiveness, you can use `xs, md, lg, xl..`